# How to make code wait for response before continue a nested promise?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have some code similar to the follow:

```
functionA (list) {
  list.forEach(fucntion (item) {
    functionB(item);
  });
}

functionB (item) {
  // format data
  service.init(item) // first promise
    .then(function (data) {
      // error handle
      (functionC (randomStuff) {
        // error handle
        service.getResponse(data) // second promise
          .then(function (response) {
            // this is the response value I need to pass back
          })
      })()
    }
})
```

I need to make the forEach loop at the beginning send one item and wait for the response before continuing on to the next item in the list. Any ideas of how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your functions asynchronous using `async` and `await` keywords, so you can resolve promises synchronously within the function:

```
async functionB(item) {
  var data = await service.init(item);

  (async functionC(randomStuff) {
    var response = await service.getResponse(data);
    return response;
  })();
}
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: The FunctionC is inside the .then of the first promise, how would you update your solution to handle that?

Comment: The `await` keyword will make the function wait for the promise returned value to be resolved to the variable, so it's like you were using `.then`. The solution do should be something like this

Comment: okay then for functionB to let functionA know it can proceed to next item in list?

Comment: Yes. The foreach will only continue when functionB ends

Answer (score -1):

Inferring from your question that each async function call depends on the result from the prior call, you can make a chain of promises in a for loop, like this...

```
function functionA(list) {
  let promiseChain = Promise.resolve();
  list.forEach(item => {
    promiseChain = promiseChain.then(result => {
      return functionB(item, result);
    });
  });
  return promiseChain;
}
```

One reason to chain sequentially like this is that each invocation of the async function requires the result of the last invocation. So here, `functionB` accepts the current item and the prior result.

```
// this function must work when priorResult == null, as it will be on the first invocation
function functionB(item, priorResult) {
  return service.init(item).then(data => { // note the returns, which are missing in the OP pseudo-code
    return service.getResponse(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: solution provided did not work in codebase

Answer (score -1):

You can use `for of` loop to do your job in `functionA` with `async` and `await`.

```js
(async function functionA(list) {
  try {
    for (const item of list) {
      const response = await functionB(item);
      //do something with response...
      console.log(response);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})(list);

async function functionB(item) {
  try {
    const randomStuff = "test";
    const data = await service.init(item);
    const response = await functionC(randomStuff)(data);
    return response;
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
}

function functionC(randomStuff) {
  return async data => {
    try {
      const response = await service.getResponse(data); // second promise
      return response;
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Cannot remove the functionB because it will break other places that use this function

Comment: @adarian, I updated my answer with function B added.